# Euler method global truncation error and conservation of orbital energy.

Tags: integration

I've been given a simplified model of a small mass orbiting a much larger one, which I need to solve using Euler's method. I've reduced the equation to two (or four, really) coupled first order ODEs:

Change in velocity: $\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} = -\frac{\vec{r}(t)}{|\vec{r}(t)|^3}$

Change in position: $\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt} = \vec{v}(t)$

I have written a program to perform the Euler integration from $t = 0$ to $200$, with $\Delta t = 0.001$, given an initial position of $\vec{r_0} = (1,0)$ and velocity $\vec{v_0} = (0, 0.5)$.

The aim is to show that the Euler method doesn't conserve orbital energy $E(t) = - \frac{GMm}{|\vec{r}(t)|} + \frac{1}{2} \vec{v}(t)^2$ (because the Euler method is a first order integration scheme).

I can clearly see by plotting the energy over time that the energy is decreasing. Also, by plotting the position of the smaller body you can see the orbit is not maintained.

At each step in the integration, I calculate the orbital energy error $\Delta E_t = (E_t - E_0) / E_0$.

I would like to express a relationship between $\Delta t$ and $\Delta E_{Fin}$ which would allow me to choose $\Delta t$ so that $\Delta E_{Fin}$ is within a certain tolerance. I'm not really sure where to start on this; I'm a little behind in the mathematics for this task.

A nudge in the right direction would mean the world to me.

---

#### Simplifications:

$GM = 1$, $m = 1$, $\vec{r_z} = \vec{v_z} = 0$

The larger body is at rest at $\vec{0}$.